# Cant create a data.frame with my findings from loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, yahoo-finance

I have a for-loop which return 4 different answeres, which is correct, but when I try to retrieve these values to my data.frame I get "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, p, 1, value = 29.1520685791182) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames"

Goal: Im trying to get values, which is printed 29, 485,-14, 12, in a data.frame

```
library("xts")
library("quantmod")
library("fredr")


Tesla <- getSymbols("TSLA", from=as.Date("2014-11-03"),to=as.Date("2019-11-03"))
Amazon <- getSymbols("AMZN", from=as.Date("2014-11-03"),to=as.Date("2019-11-03"))
Equinor <- getSymbols("EQNR",from="2014-11-03",to="2019-11-03")
FTSE100 <- getSymbols("^FTSE",from="2014-11-03",to="2019-11-03")

dftest <- data.frame(merge(TSLA$TSLA.Close, AMZN$AMZN.Close, EQNR$EQNR.Close,FTSE$FTSE.Close))

df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 4)) #The data.frame where i want my returned values from print(pros) to be in.
colnames(dfProsent) <- c("TESLA", "AMAZON","EQUINOR","FTSE")

for (p in dftest) {
  pros <- ((last(as.numeric(p)))-(first(as.numeric(p))))/(first(as.numeric(p)))*100
  print(pros) #this print out 29, 485,-14,12
df[p,1] <- pros #the problem
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you looking something like this: `for (p in 1:dim(dftest)[2]) {
  pros <- ((last(as.numeric(dftest[,p])))-(first(as.numeric(dftest[,p]))))/(first(as.numeric(dftest[,p])))*100
  dfProsent[1,p] <- pros
  print(pros)
}`. Please explain...

Comment: im trying to get the values which is printed in print(pros) to a data.frame

Comment: Understood if you are calculating the last and first values for each brand to calculate the percentage change, then you should use the code I suggested. If it's not what you are after, then we need more clarification.

Comment: I think you should loop through the row number, like for(p in 1:nrow(df)). So pros is a vector of length 4, and it is not clear what is the dimension or length of  df[p,1]

Comment: When I run the for-loop it returns 29,485, -14, 12 (which is printed out with print(pros)). I want these numbers in a data.frame.

Comment: @StupidWolf not sure if you understood my problem (or I didnt understand your respond). But anyway im trying to get the values printed with print(pros) in a data.frame. (in the data.frame named df)